# How to customize login page in theme-tabler Backpack for Laravel

Tags: laravel-backpack

How to customize login page in theme-tabler Backpack for Laravel?

I have copy .../vendor/backpack/theme-tabler/resources/views/auth/login/illustration.blade.php

to .../resources/views/vendor/backpack/theme-tabler/views/auth/login/illustration.blade.php

But, I still it did not make any change

Comment: Your view path is incorrect. Use the following path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Publish config `php artisan vendor:publish --tag="theme-tabler-config"`
2. Change `'auth_layout' => 'illustration'` in `config/backpack/theme-tabler.php`
3. Copy the view to the following path:

`resources/views/vendor/backpack/theme-tabler/auth/login/illustration.blade.php`